# É possivel codificar linha por linha em base64?

Tags: php, desempenho

Tenho um código que pega arquivos binários e os converte em base64, porém existem arquivos muito grandes e isto acaba usando muito da memória da máquina (e até mesmo do processo). Para ler arquivos grandes geralmente (sem convertê-los) eu faço isto:

```
$handle = fopen('ARQUIVO', 'rb');

while (false === feof($handle)) {
    $data = fgets($handle);
    ...
}

fclose($handle);
```

Assim evito exceder a memória e outros problemas do gênero. Mas o problemas é que com [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) eu necessito dos dados completos (a `string` inteira).

Como codificar arquivos binários grandes sem perder o desempenho?

Comment: Sim.
[Veja:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920780/is-it-possible-to-base64-encode-a-file-in-chunks) Mas seus pedaços tem que ser em tamanhos múltiplos de 3 em questão de bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim, o código abaixo foi retirado de um [**comentário**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php#92762) sobre a função [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php).

```
$fh = fopen('Input-File', 'rb'); 
//$fh2 = fopen('Output-File', 'wb'); 

$cache = ''; 
$eof = false; 

while (1) { 
    if (!$eof) { 
        if (!feof($fh)) { 
            $row = fgets($fh, 4096); 
        } else { 
            $row = ''; 
            $eof = true; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($cache !== '') 
        $row = $cache.$row; 
    elseif ($eof) 
        break; 

    $b64 = base64_encode($row); 
    $put = ''; 

    if (strlen($b64) < 76) { 
        if ($eof) { 
            $put = $b64."\n"; 
            $cache = ''; 
        } else { 
            $cache = $row; 
        } 

    } elseif (strlen($b64) > 76) { 
        do { 
            $put .= substr($b64, 0, 76)."\n"; 
            $b64 = substr($b64, 76); 
        } while (strlen($b64) > 76); 

        $cache = base64_decode($b64); 

    } else { 
        if (!$eof && $b64{75} == '=') { 
            $cache = $row; 
        } else { 
            $put = $b64."\n"; 
            $cache = ''; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($put !== '') { 
        echo $put; 
        //fputs($fh2, $put); 
        //fputs($fh2, base64_decode($put));
    } 
} 

//fclose($fh2); 
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Só uma nota: Alterei o tamanho de 4096 para 32 `$row = fgets($fh, 32);` e utilizei `memory_get_usage()` e `memory_get_peak_usage()` com uma image de 2,75Mb, tive os seguintes resultados: Inicial: memory 224488 e
memory_peak 237032

/ Final:
memory 224792
memory_peak 241600